# бот не реагирует на нажатие кнопки 'Услуги"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
      markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
      detailes = types.KeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе')
      services = types.KeyboardButton('Услуги')
      instruction = types.KeyboardButton('Инструкция')
      markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствуем вас!', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Детали о сервисе':
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в меню')
        markup1.add(back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "fffff", reply_markup=markup1)
    elif message.text == 'Назад в меню':
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)
           markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
           detailes = types.KeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе')
           services = types.KeyboardButton('Услуги')
           instruction = types.KeyboardButton('Инструкция')
           markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите информацию для отображения:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Услуги':
        markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        ps = types.KeyboardButton('fff')
        xb = types.KeyboardButton('lll')
        ap = types.KeyboardButton('sss')
        pm = types.KeyboardButton('ppp')
        back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в меню')
        markup2.add(ps, xb, ap, pm, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите платформу', reply_markup=markup2)
    elif message.text == 'Назад в меню':
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)
           markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
           detailes = types.KeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе')
           services = types.KeyboardButton('Услуги')
           instruction = types.KeyboardButton('Инструкция')
           markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите информацию для отображения:', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не настроены параметры фильтрации сообщений в хендлерах. Вам нужно либо обрабатывать все сообщения в одном хендлере, принимающим на вход все входящие сообщения `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)`. Либо создавать для каждой команды собственный обработчик.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Назад в меню")
def back_to_menu_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    detailes = types.KeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе')
    services = types.KeyboardButton('Услуги')
    instruction = types.KeyboardButton('Инструкция')
    markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите информацию для отображения:', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Детали о сервисе")
def get_user_text(message):
    markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в меню')
    markup1.add(back)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "fffff", reply_markup=markup1)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Услуги")
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Услуги':
    markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    ps = types.KeyboardButton('fff')
    xb = types.KeyboardButton('lll')
    ap = types.KeyboardButton('sss')
    pm = types.KeyboardButton('ppp')
    back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в меню')
    markup2.add(ps, xb, ap, pm, back)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите платформу', reply_markup=markup2)
```